# Can I define a .net method to accept parameters with variable definitions?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Defined (Where DbSet1,2,3 are identical definitions):

```
Context1
  DbSet1
  DbSet2
  DbSet3

Context2
  DbSet1
  DbSet2
  DbSet3

Context3
  DbSet1
  DbSet2
  DbSet3

Context4   (where DbSet4,5,6 are supersets of DbSet1,2,3)
  DbSet4
  DbSet5
  DbSet6
```

It is desired to perform standard operations on and between the contexts.  This might be things like Clear, Backup, Load, Seed, Copy, etc.  Copy is used below as an example where the various datasets are copied between contexts.  The 4th method below is slightly different because Context4 is slightly different from Contexts1,2,3.

```
Sub Method1 (db1 as Context1, db2 as Context2)
  Copy_db1_to_db2()
End

Sub Method2 (db1 as Context1, db3 as Context3)
  Copy_db1_to_db3()
End

Sub Method3 (db2 as Context2, db3 as Context3)
  Copy_db2_to_db3()
End

Method4 (db1 as Context1, db4 as Context4)
  Copy_db1_to_db4()
End
```

Is it possible, and if so, how do we define a method so that the various methods 1,2,3 are consolidated into a single methodX that can accept the different contexts?  My experience is limited to understanding that the parameters of a method are specifically declared so that using the methods above, the following would not work:

```
Method3(Context1,Context3)
```

This would fail because Method3 expects the first parameter to be of type Context2.

But inside each of Methods 1,2,3 the code would be identical; the only difference with these methods is the Context declarations in the parameters definition.  I’m assuming there’s an elegant way to define a single methodX that would allow different contexts to be passed in as long as the references within that methodX are consistent with the various Context declarations.

Method4 is a slightly different issue because Context4 has additional tables/fields defined.  But except for the additional tables/fields, the remainder of the operations would address DbSets 1,2,3 the same.  Assuming there is a way to do what I’m asking, would that also accommodate the slightly different Context4 as long as the code in MethodX remains consistent with all the Contexts being passed in?

**Added to post after further investigation:**

Before following the answer in the first post below I tried the following:

```
Sub Method1 (db1 as Object, db2 as Object)
  Code that performs the operations
End
```

By not typing Method1's parameters with specific context types, it accepts and works properly with Contexts 1-3.  I'm assuming if I attempted references to the differences in Context 4 things will blow up.  But if I just have code that works on Contexts 1-3 it seems like a great solution to reuse code on these various contexts with identical databases but different connection strings.  Am I missing something?

**So my follow up question:**  Is this bad practice or is it a legitimate use of the type 'Object'?

Comment: Use interfaces and/or generics.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant by generics, but please see my addition above.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, but one option is to overload them:

```
Sub Method (db1 as Context1, db2 as Context2)
   Copy_db1_to_db2()
End

Sub Method (db1 as Context1, db3 as Context3)
   Copy_db1_to_db3()
End

Sub Method (db2 as Context2, db3 as Context3)
   Copy_db2_to_db3()
End

Sub Method (db1 as Context1, db4 as Context4)
   Copy_db1_to_db4()
End
```

If you want to have common code, pull out the common bits of all the Contexts into an interface (let's say `IContext`), and have a private method that the public overloads call; something like

```
Private Sub Copy (db1 as IContext, db2 as IContext)
   ...
End
```

and then

```
Sub Method (db1 as Context1, db2 as Context2)
   Copy(db1, db2)
End

Sub Method (db1 as Context1, db3 as Context3)
   Copy(db1, db3)
End

Sub Method (db2 as Context2, db3 as Context3)
   Copy(db2, db3)
End

Sub Method (db1 as Context1, db4 as Context4)
   Copy(db1, db4)

   ' Custom bits for v4 here
End
```